# Do I get the Class Feats at level 1 in D&D 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, class-feature

I'm a bit confused about Class Feats. PHB says characters gain one Feat on first level. However, it seems reasonable for me that characters get these on first level. So, do I get them then, or do I have to "buy" them separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each Class Feat (Feats with a prerequisite of that class) must be taken using your feats.

Each Class Feature (Features listed in the class description) are gained automatically at first level.

Comment: I was thinking of the second type, sorry for not making it clear. Thank you for making it clear!

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai: Note that some features are a choice. For example, a wizard's Implement Mastery feature gives them a choice of several abilities; they get one of them, not all of them, because they're all part of a single class feature.

Comment: @ObliviousSage yes, I know about that, it was clear by the book. The only thing was this little difference between Class Feats and Class Features (nice naming convention... :) )